# Shuffling of the training data for LightGBM

Tags: lightgbm

Do I need to externally shuffle the training dataset before passing it to lightgbm train function? Please assume that I DO NOT use lgbm's Cross Validation methods.

Answer (score 1):

In the [official example](https://github.com/azure/mmlspark/blob/master/notebooks/samples/LightGBM%20-%20Quantile%20Regression%20for%20Drug%20Discovery.ipynb) they don't shuffle the data. It is very common for tree based models to not require manual shuffling. So NO, you don't need to shuffle.

Answer (score -1):

It Will greatly depend on your data structure, data size and the problem you are trying to solve to name a few of many possibilities. But without an example, it is only a guess.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.